# Best way to achieve complicated numeric formatting in C#

Tags: c#, string-formatting

What is the best way to replicate the behaviour of something like this in C#?

```
// Converts decimal to a 0-padded string with minimum specified width and precision.
sprintf(out, "%0*.*lf", width, precision, decimal);
```

I had a read of [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) and [composite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) format strings, but I can't see any nice way to achieve this.

The reason I ask is that I just came across this ugly snippet in some code I am maintaining where we are required to format a bunch of decimals according to variable widths and precisions as specified by an external interface:

```
private static String ZEROS = "00000000000000000000000000";

public override string Format(decimal input, int width, int precision)
{
    String formatString = ZEROS.Substring(0, width - precision - 1) 
                          + "." + ZEROS.Substring(0, precision);
    return ToDecimal(input).ToString(formatString);
}
```

and I would like to replace it with someing a little less horrendous.

**UPDATE**

Since the final answer is buried in comments, here it is:

```
public override string Format(decimal input, int width, int precision)
{
    string.Format("{0," + width + ":F" + precision + "}", input).Replace(" ","0");
}
```

In my case the input is always positive so this works too:

```
public override string Format(decimal input, int width, int precision)
{
    return input.ToString("F"+precision).PadLeft(width, 0);
}
```

Comment: why do you call ToDecimal() on an input param which is already decimal?

Comment: also, presumably you have guards in the full code for precision passed greater than width?

Comment: Note also that the `Format` method is buggy, because the resulting string might not be rounded correctly. (Also there's no check to see if the total width is greater than the length of ZEROS, but I presume that the input is always checked.)

Comment: @MitchWheat: Because the guy who wrote this code wasn't the greatest coder ever. :)

Comment: @Porges: Yes, the passed in values will always fit into the specified spaces, etc. The method works fine as-is; I was just looking for a less long, confusing and ugly version.

Comment: consider: Regular Code Inspections.

Comment: Disregard the part of my comment about rounding, by the way. It's incorrect (I can't edit it now).

Comment: @MitchWheat: We have code inspections now, this code is old, old, old. The guy who wrote it left the company before I even started. Also, it works as-is because the inputs are guaranteed to be good (i.e. not exceed the length of the ZEROS string, width > precision + 1, etc.) Note however, that "currently works" is a far cry from "is good code". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write it like this, generating a standard format string and then using it:

```
public static string Format(decimal input, int width, int precision)
{
    var format = string.Format("{{0,{0}:F{1}}}", width, precision);
    // generates (e.g. width=15, precision=5)  "{0,15:F5}"
    // then format using this and replace padding with zeroes
    return string.Format(format, input).Replace(" ", "0");
}
```

Or instead of calling format twice just concat the format string, depending on your preference:

```
string.Format("{0," + width + ":F" + precision + "}", input).Replace(" ","0")
```

You have to replace the spaces afterwards since there's no way to specify the padding character. Alternately you could write your own formatter to pad with a specific character. This works though :)

**Edit:** This matches the original for all inputs except when `precision = 0`. In that case, the original is incorrect, since it counts the decimal point as part of the width even when it isn't present.

**Oops:** Forgot to check negative numbers.

Here is a simpler version, but have to check if the number is negative to get the padding correct:

```
public override string Format(decimal input, int width, int precision)
{
    var output = input.ToString("F" + precision);
    return input < 0
        ? "-" + output.Substring(1).PadLeft(width, '0')
        :       output             .PadLeft(width, '0');
}
```

Comment: @Porges: I like the second version best out of the options proposed so far--it seems like the easiest to read (short, clean, no extra constructor calls). It would be nice to avoid the `Replace()` if possible, but you can't have everything I suppose. :(

Comment: I've added a simpler version which avoids `Replace`.

Comment: @Porges: Currently `precision` is guaranteed to be between 2 and 5 so the 0 case is not a problem. Nice catch though. :)

Comment: Sorry I messed this up a bit since I forgot to check if it worked for negative numbers. I've updated with a simple version that does work - but it is a little longer.

Comment: In our case the values are always positive so I've decided to go with: `input.ToString("F" + precision).PadLeft(width, '0');`. In the general case I would probably prefer the `Replace()` version to the ternary operator though. Thanks for all the great suggestions!

Comment: @Porges: Actually I think your `Substring` and `PadLeft` are the wrong way around. In any case I would just use `PadLeft(width-1, '0')` and avoid the substring entirely.

Comment: @Porges: Nevermind, I just relised you are stripping the '-' not the leading numeral. My mistake!

Comment: @veredesmarald: Yeah, I have to remove the '-' then pad and replace it, otherwise you end up with something like `0000-12.1123`

Comment: @Porges: Yep, and after that mix-up I definitely prefer the `Replace()` version for clarity. :)

Comment: @veredesmarald: the first one doesn't handle negative values correctly, the second one with if statement does - might want to update your post (sometimes I wish SO had a message feature!)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
return input.ToString(new string('0', width) + '.' + new string('0', precision));
```

?

Edit: acutally, here's a better one:

```
return input.ToString(new string('0', width - 1).insert(width - precision, '.'));
```

Comment: I've decided to go with Porges suggestion since I find it easier to understand at a glance (no constructor calls or arithmetic required), but this is also a good, short solution. Also the first length has to be `width - precision - 1`. :)

Comment: @veredesmarald: Edited, I found a better way (I suppose it doesn't matter, though).

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to get rid of the `ZERO` would be

```
public override string Format(decimal input, int width, int precision)
{
    String formatString = new string('0', width - precision - 1) 
                      + "." + new string('0', precision);
    return ToDecimal(input).ToString(formatString);
}
```

Not sure if you can do much else.

Answer (score 0):

This is about as good as it gets:

```
public static string double2string( double value , int integerDigits , int fractionalDigits )
{
  string        decimalPoint = CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator ;
  StringBuilder sb           = new StringBuilder() ;

  sb.Append('0',integerDigits)
    .Append(decimalPoint)
    .Append('0',fractionalDigits)
    ;
  return value.ToString( sb.ToString() ) ;
}
```

Comment: Is the `decimalPoint` part necessary? I thought any `.` characters in a format string got converted to the appropriate decimal separator automagically? Also is there any benefit to using string builder over the shorter versions posted that just construct two strings and cat them with `"."`?

Answer (score -1):

I beleive you could just call [`Decimal.ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ebe5aks.aspx) and pass it a [Custom Numeric Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) that you can generate.

Comment: So why was my answer down-voted when it is a less verbose version of the accepted answer?