# double number formatting

Tags: c#, formatting, double

ALL,

I am trying to read the value of 1.5 from the initialization file and present it as 1.50000 in the text control in Windows Forms.

Here is the code:

```
string value = ini.Read( "Form", "value" );
this.textcontrol.Text = String.Format( "{0:F5}", value );
```

The "value" variable does contain 1.5 but the text control also shows 1.5 instead of 1.50000.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

As suggested I tried to do following:

```
var doublevar = double.Parse( value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture );
this.textcontrol.Text = doublevar.ToString( "{0:F5}" );
```

but what I did see in the control is {1:F5}.

Any idea?

[/EDIT]

Comment: You'll need to convert it to double first before F5 does anything meaningful.  Use double.Parse().

Comment: Checkout this link for examples of how to do this in a different way as well 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104767/best-way-to-achieve-complicated-numeric-formatting-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be like this

```
string value = ini.Read( "Form", "value" );
this.textcontrol.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00000}",  double.Parse(value));
```

Here is more details [String Format for Double [C#]](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/)

Comment: Why would this work? Variable `value` is still of type `string` and can't possibly be formatted correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You are reading value as string. You want to convert it do double for such formatting to work.

```
string valueText = ini.Read( "Form", "value" );
var value  = double.Parse(valueText);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the value to decimal variable.

Below code example would work.

```
decimal value = 1.5m;
this.txtEditAcquisitionUpb.Text = String.Format( "{0:F5}", value );
```

Answer (score 1):

Combining other answers to get it right:

```
string valueString = ini.Read("Form", "value");
double valueDouble = double.Parse(valueString);
this.textcontrol.Text = valueDouble.ToString("F5");
```

If there's a chance this will run on machines with varying `CultureInfo`, then consider using overloads of `Parse` and `ToString` that include an `IFormatProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8s7t687.aspx

Also try:

```
double.Parse(value);
```